# Perdendo valor dos campos POST quando conexão do usuário está lenta

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

Estou com um problema quando usuários atualizam o site e no meio da ação a conexão dele fica lenta ou cai e volta rapidamente na hora do processo.

As vezes o usuário só atualiza o título de uma notícia, por exemplo, mas na hora de salvar, o arquivo salvar.php que faz o UPDATE no mysql por algum motivo perde os valores que deveriam estar no _POST de todos os campos e salva tudo em branco por cima do que estava, pois o ID da tabela vem via GET (e este valor não perde, pois está na URL).

Isso ocorre geralmente quando a conexão do usuário fica instável durante o processo. Existe alguma forma de validar e/ou evitar que se percam estes dados?

Segue exemplo:

```
<?
$idBanner   = $_GET["id"];
$Titulo     = $_POST['Titulo'];
$Resumo     = $_POST['Resumo'];

$consulta="UPDATE site_banner SET Titulo='$Titulo', Resumo='$Resumo' WHERE idBanner = '$idBanner' ";
$con=mysql_query($consulta,$db) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=banner.php'>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça o teste no post antes de colocar no banco:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // coloque seu codigo aqui;
}
else {
    // devolva para o usuário uma mensagem ou retorne para o form;
}
```

Saudações